# Are questions regarding data quality on topic?

Tags: discussion

I saw the question "[Is www.multpl.com reliable?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/17758/8815)" and im wondering if it is on topic for the site?

Should we evaluate data quality is that opinionated?

Comment: Seems answerable to me. If answer focuses on data sources, and provides some minimal check that data is consistent with primary sources, I see no problem for that to be a good, non-opinionated answer.

Comment: @luchonacho I would think sites like opendata.SE is more appropriate, since its focus is dealing with data and data quality.

Comment: I see it as a good opportunity to provide answers on "how to know if i can trust a site with economic data?" 
I also thought maybe it fits into the startup discussion exchange, as multiples are often used for valuations and VCs.